# select default value form::input_dropdown_list

Tags: php, html, database

I have a form with fields, the fields cumin from DB.
I'm trying to set a default value - that is select automatically
Appends the code

```
                    'queue_id' => [ 
                                    'type' => Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
                                    'items' =>$queues ,  
                                    'options' => [ 
                                            'prompt' => '--Select '.Yii::t ( 'app', 'Queue' ).'--'
                                    ] 
                            ],


                            'user_assigned_id' => [ 
                                    'type' => Form::INPUT_DROPDOWN_LIST,
                                    'items' =>$users,
                                    'options' => [
                                            'prompt' => '--'.Yii::t ( 'app', 'Select User' ).'--'
                                    ] 
                            ], 


                    'ticket_category_id_1' => [
```